# Entity Framework and AngularJS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to get theory down. I recently have been looking into AngularJS and wanted to integrate it with Microsoft's MVC5 pattern along side of Entity Framework 6.

My question is will I end up using EF with AngularJS? Will I need to use the ASP.net Web API to create an API for Angular to run off of?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Entity Framework is one technology choice that could be chosen to persist data to a relational database; there are many others that you could equally end up using. AngularJS will run on the client side, EF will run on the server side so you can use both together. As to what you use to transfer data between the client and server, ASP.NET web api would be a decent choice, as would Nancy, ServiceStack or any other framework for building REST APIs

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you're wanting to integrate EF with MVC, then yes, you'll end up using them both. You'll use WebAPI to create the REST API for AngularJS to query (through either $q/promises or $http).

If you really want to make it a full SPA, you really don't need MVC except to provide the routing to the MVC view and for any routing into the SPA app. You'll make greater use of the WebAPI in this case.

Additionally, you might take a look at using [Breeze](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/entity-framework-dbcontext) with both EF and WebAPI.

Comment: Not only will you probably want to use webapi but you'll also probably have at least a couple views/etc for the app.

Comment: @Xaniff: MSDN says your code is not yet published, btw.

Comment: That's peculiar.. It worked at one point. I'll see if I can't find a new link to it.